# I'm trying to replicate a jsfiddle to no avail

Tags: jquery

I'm very green with jquery so don't be too harsh. 
Here is the jsfiddle I'm trying to use http://jsfiddle.net/RBKaZ/. I get an error on the `$("#dialog").dialog({` line:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

Aslo the Div is showing unlike on jsfiddle.

Here is my page:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default4.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function () {
            $("#nameentered").text($("#name").val());
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#open").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
})
</script>

<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

<div id="dialog">
    <p>Please enter your name</p>
    <textarea id="name"></textarea>
</div>

<label>Name entered: </label>
<label id="nameentered"></label>
<br />
<input type="button" id="open" value="Open Dialog" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I downloaded jquery-1.9.1.js from jquery.com and put it in my scripts folder. On jsfiddle they say they use jquery UI 1.9.2. Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**
I've added this and I get rid of the object not supported error, but it still doesn't do anything.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You need to put the jquery ui script in that folder as well, and include it.

Comment: Add this to your code. I just linked google CDN. Or you can download and add your own <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 5):

Add this script (jQuery UI) below your jQuery script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I added the script as `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` I added the type because my developer said it needed it. But before I added that "type" it still didn't do anything...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you need both jQuery and jQuery UI, they're two different libraries.

- [jQuery](http://jquery.com)
- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com)

Comment: im downloading ui to see if better solution

Comment: So I put the folder I unzipped into my Scripts folder and I try calling it like this: 
`<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom" type="text/javascript"></script>
` and I get the same error, but when I use the `ajax.google` on it gets rid of the error, but still doesnt work.

Comment: Okay added this and it gets rid of error, but nothing happens. `<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` `<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` `<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: You only need to include jQuery UI once! Check if the scripts have loaded by opening your browser's developer tools and making sure the `jQuery` and `jQuery.ui` objects exist.

Comment: What I need to do was have the jquery run on `$(document).ready(function () {` So i put that before `$("#dialog").dialog({`, with a closing tag, and it worked.

Comment: Good. Glad it's working for you!

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $("#nameentered").text($("#name").val());
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#open").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
}); 

</script>
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!